# How do I perform something like rolling the controller shock button on keyboard properly?

Tags: controllers, keyboard, castlevania-lords-of-shadow

Nowadays, I am playing *Castlevania: Lords of Shadow* using my PC with a keyboard.

Unfortunately, other ports on the case are broken and I can't attach a controller. Also, I dislike wireless controllers.

I'm stuck in one of the stages and I know it requires rolling the shock button in a controller.

[This](https://www.ign.com/wikis/castlevania-lords-of-shadow/Chapter_Two_-_Sanctuary_of_Titans) is that exact stage. The titan throws a rock at my character and I should grab the rock with my bands, rolling it around myself, and throw it back to the Titan.

To roll the rock, the player should perform the shock-button rolling (which is highlighted in the game itself in a hint). But the problem is that it's so hard to perform this action using a keyboard.

I tried to push the arrow directional keys repeatedly and to push A, S, W, D keys repeatedly; but both techniques have failed.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game may be expecting the full input with the diagonal directions, like `up`, `up+left`, `left`, `left+down`, and so on.

Have you tried pushing `W`, then pressing `A` without releasing `W`, release `W`, press `S`, release `A`, press `D`, release `S`, press `W`, ... ?

Making the sequence: `W`, `W+A`, `A`, `A+S`, `S`, `S+D`, `D`, `D+W`, `W`

---

Another option would be to try a software like GlovePIE or AutoHotkey and create a macro to perform the required input.